# Android add footer view for AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I would like to add a footer view to the drop down list of an AutoCompleteTextView.
Any idea about how doing this?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do this since you don't have access to ListPopupWindow in AutoCompleteTextView.
You cannot manipulate view of dropdown. You'll have to implement your own EditText with dropdown to achieve this.